# Is there a Windows utility to delete contents of RAM left by an application?

Tags: windows, security, memory, privacy, forensics

Ideally, this utility would know where in physical RAM an application was and completely clear its contents when it's closed.  Does anyone know of such a utility?

Comment: What would you expect to be the result of this? When a process exits, all memory it allocated is automatically freed.

Comment: What's the possible threat here? If you're worried about live forensics, unplugging the system does usually work, and very often people do it anyway. Considering the window for a freeze attack is *tiny*, adding a physical lock to a case and pulling the cord should utterly negate most forms of memory acquisition, live or offline.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg and Journeyman Geek: I am a bit worried about live forensics, and am looking for a solution to zero out an area of RAM when a restart would not be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows already zeros all free Memory before it is used again (zero page thread):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2010/10/29/pdc10-mysteries-of-windows-memory-management-revealed-part-two.aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jaystech.com/2007/12/how-to-clear-your-ram-without.html

1. Right click anywhere on your desktop.
2. Point over “New”, then select “Shortcut”.
3. Copy the below line (as it is):

   > %windir%\system32\rundll32.exe advapi32.dll,ProcessIdleTasks
4. Paste it there & click “Next”.
5. Give it a name like Clear RAM
6. That’s it, run it every time your computer goes slow.

Comment: Thats a bit of an urban myth - [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5033518/debunking-common-windows-performance-tweaking-myths) points at [microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463004.aspx#E1E), which disagrees with this